# C++ const variable in function declaration

Tags: c++, reference, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262)

I am trying to understand how `const` works in a function parameter. What is the difference between `void function(int const *&i);` and `void function(const int *&i);`? And I would appreciate if you gave an example of their implementation and of the usage of `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, just read it from right to left:

> First example: i is a reference to a pointer of a constant integer.
>
> Second example: i is a reference to a pointer of an integer constant.

The placement of const only changes things on either side of the pointer. For example:

`const int* i`

means: i is a pointer to a constant integer

whereas `int* const i`

means: i is a constant pointer to an integer.

Comment: can I assign a variable to i in this function, if yes, how?

Comment: @ibrahim: Of course you can. You can do it as usual. Like this `i = p;` where `p` is some value implicitly convertible to `const int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Those declarations are equivalent. For more info, see [this page](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html).

Answer (score 0):

Best place for const correctness is the  - [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)

Answer (score 0):

They're both the same.

It means a reference to a pointer to a const int.